# Why does this erlang ssh daemon repond with 'no hostkey alg'?

Tags: macos, ssh, erlang

I'm a little confused with the OTP ssh daemon implementation's behaviour and I wonder if someone might clear things up for me. Preliminaries; I have the following program:

```
-module(sshd).

-export([start/0, stop/1]).

-spec start() -> {ok, ssh:ssh_daemon_ref()} | {error, atom()}.
start() ->
    _ = application:start(crypto),
    _ = application:start(ssh),

    Opts = [
            {system_dir, "/etc/erl_sshd/"},
            {pwdfun, fun passwd/2}
           ],

    ssh:daemon(2222, Opts).

-spec stop(ssh:ssh_daemon_ref()) -> ok.
stop(Ref) ->
    ssh:stop_daemon(Ref).

%% ===================================================================                  
%%  Internal Functions                                                                  
%% ===================================================================                  

-spec passwd(User::string(), Password::string()) -> boolean().
passwd(User, User) ->
    true;
passwd(_User, _Password) ->
    false.
```

and have created `/tmp/erl_sshd` on disk as follows:

```
> mkdir /tmp/erl_sshd
> ssh-keygen -t rsa -f /tmp/erl_sshd/ssh_host_rsa_key
Generating public/private rsa key pair.
Enter passphrase (empty for no passphrase): 
Enter same passphrase again: 
Your identification has been saved in /tmp/erl_sshd/ssh_host_rsa_key.
Your public key has been saved in /tmp/erl_sshd/ssh_host_rsa_key.pub.
The key fingerprint is:
...
```

Testing with OpenSSHd:

```
> /usr/sbin/sshd -p 2222 -h /tmp/erl_sshd/ssh_host_rsa_key -d   
debug1: sshd version OpenSSH_5.6p1
debug1: read PEM private key done: type RSA
debug1: private host key: #0 type 1 RSA
debug1: setgroups() failed: Operation not permitted
debug1: rexec_argv[0]='/usr/sbin/sshd'
debug1: rexec_argv[1]='-p'
debug1: rexec_argv[2]='2222'
debug1: rexec_argv[3]='-h'
debug1: rexec_argv[4]='/tmp/erl_sshd/ssh_host_rsa_key'
debug1: rexec_argv[5]='-d'
debug1: Bind to port 2222 on 0.0.0.0.
Server listening on 0.0.0.0 port 2222.
debug1: Bind to port 2222 on ::.
Server listening on :: port 2222.
```

I can get a prompt no problem:

```
> ssh localhost -p 2222 -v
OpenSSH_5.6p1, OpenSSL 0.9.8r 8 Feb 2011
debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh_config
debug1: Applying options for *
debug1: Applying options for *
debug1: Connecting to localhost [::1] port 2222.
debug1: Connection established.
debug1: identity file /Users/blt/.ssh/id_rsa type 1
debug1: identity file /Users/blt/.ssh/id_rsa-cert type -1
debug1: identity file /Users/blt/.ssh/id_dsa type -1
debug1: identity file /Users/blt/.ssh/id_dsa-cert type -1
debug1: Remote protocol version 2.0, remote software version OpenSSH_5.6
debug1: match: OpenSSH_5.6 pat OpenSSH*
debug1: Enabling compatibility mode for protocol 2.0
debug1: Local version string SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_5.6
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT sent
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT received
debug1: kex: server->client aes128-ctr hmac-md5 none
debug1: kex: client->server aes128-ctr hmac-md5 none
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEX_DH_GEX_REQUEST(1024<1024<8192) sent
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_KEX_DH_GEX_GROUP
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEX_DH_GEX_INIT sent
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_KEX_DH_GEX_REPLY
debug1: checking without port identifier
The authenticity of host '[localhost]:2222 ([::1]:2222)' can't be established.
RSA key fingerprint is 01:0e:c6:0b:f4:48:ab:0a:49:2a:66:38:27:67:8f:52.
Are you sure you want to continue connecting (yes/no)? ^C
```

When I start the erlang sshd, though:

```
> erl
Erlang R15B03 (erts-5.9.3) [source] [64-bit] [smp:8:8] [async-threads:0] [hipe] [kernel-poll:false]

Eshell V5.9.3  (abort with ^G)
1> c(sshd), {ok, Ref} = sshd:start().
{ok,<0.49.0>}
2>
```

no luck:

```
> ssh localhost -p 2222 -v                                    
OpenSSH_5.6p1, OpenSSL 0.9.8r 8 Feb 2011
debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh_config
debug1: Applying options for *
debug1: Applying options for *
debug1: Connecting to localhost [::1] port 2222.
debug1: Connection established.
debug1: identity file /Users/blt/.ssh/id_rsa type 1
debug1: identity file /Users/blt/.ssh/id_rsa-cert type -1
debug1: identity file /Users/blt/.ssh/id_dsa type -1
debug1: identity file /Users/blt/.ssh/id_dsa-cert type -1
debug1: Remote protocol version 2.0, remote software version Erlang
debug1: no match: Erlang
debug1: Enabling compatibility mode for protocol 2.0
debug1: Local version string SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_5.6
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT sent
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT received
debug1: kex: server->client aes128-cbc hmac-sha1 none
debug1: kex: client->server aes128-cbc hmac-sha1 none
no hostkey alg
```

Aside from creating a user, I've done the same steps as outlined in the [User Guide](http://www.erlang.org/doc/apps/ssh/using_ssh.html#id60528) and have covered the same ground as [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13661929/erlang-ssh-daemon-no-hostkey-alg). I'm on an OS X system:

```
> sw_vers
ProductName:    Mac OS X
ProductVersion: 10.7.5
BuildVersion:   11G63
```

If I run the erlang shell as the root user and redirect `system_dir` to `/etc` all works as expected. Is it clear to anyone else what's up? Perhaps user permissions on the `/tmp/erl_sshd` directory that erlang is silently erroring out on? I had previously turned the sasl application on, but nothing in the output jumped out at me as pertinent.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like when setting `{system_dir, "/etc/erl_sshd/"}` that it should really be `/tmp/erl_sshd/`. You have added all of the daemon files to `/tmp/erl_sshd`. When running OpenSSH you also use the `/tmp/erl_sshd` with the correct files.